# How do I scale a chapter heading in memoir?

Tags: fonts, memoir, chapters, fontspec

I am (or rather, would like to be) using [League Gothic](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/league-gothic), pinched a bit together.

Here's what I got:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\title}{League Gothic}
\newcommand{\titlefont}[1]{{\scalebox{2.0}[0.8]{\title{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}}

\chapterstyle{section}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\titlefont}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\end{document}
```

I understand that I can't mix `\newfontfamily` and `\newcommand` like that, but what is the proper approach?

Comment: Remark: You should never call a font family `\title` as there is a `\title` macro in standard LaTeX.

Comment: Also you need `graphicx` for `\scalebox` and `\chaptitlefont` never gets an argument, you probably want to redefine `\printchaptertitle` instead, to get access to the title.

Comment: @TeXnician, I was actually wondering if `\title` was reserved, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to at least do something

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newfontfamily{\titlefont}[Path = ./,]{LeagueGothic-Regular}
\chapterstyle{section}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{{\scalebox{8.0}[0.8]{\normalfont\titlefont\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\end{document}
```

I've added `\normalfont` since no bold version of the font is loaded

Comment: Thanks, Lars. I'm looking to center it now, I have tried inserting a `\centering` here and there with no luck. Where should it be?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard scaled against what? The scalebox makes a unit on its own. It might be better to post a new question instead.

Comment: Centered horizontally ... Yes, considering a new question.